# repeated setTimeout() with 1 milisec

Tags: jquery

Here is a piece of code from the jQuery source (bit.ly/jqsource):

```
// The DOM ready check for Internet Explorer
function doScrollCheck() {
    if ( jQuery.isReady ) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        // If IE is used, use the trick by Diego Perini
        // http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/
        document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
    } catch(e) {
        setTimeout( doScrollCheck, 1 );
        return;
    }

    // and execute any waiting functions
    jQuery.ready();
}
```

It is a hack to detect when the DOM is ready for IE. While theoretically this seems very beautiful, I'm a little concerned about `setTimeout( doScrollCheck, 1 );`, which means that the function `doScrollCheck()` is called 1000 times per sec before the DOM is ready.

Should I expect this to be a huge performance drain?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how this *wouldn't* be a performance drain. At the very least you're locking up the browser, which is never a good idea.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. Why *isn't* it a performance drain? (Because I'm assuming the jQuery people are doing a good job here.)

Comment: IE has (or had?) a minimum `setTimeout/setInterval` duration of something like `13ms`, so it isn't quite as bad as 1000/second. More like 77/second. Of all the IE performance issues, I've never heard a complaint of jQuery's `.ready()` being a major drain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function is almost *never* called at exactly the requested time. The browser is free to do a +/- on the time by a few milliseconds, at the least, and if there is any other intensive work going on then it can be delayed by *seconds* or more. As others have already mentioned, the browser also implements a minimum timeout time. This 1 millisecond simply tells the browser 'as soon as you're done doing whatever you're doing, let me know so I can do something'. It also yields execution from the Javascript so that the browser can return to doing whatever it will do next.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is - until the DOM is ready user can't iteract with a page anyway and the every-1ms-checking is stopped as soon as DOM has been prepared.

Plus, this doScrollCheck function isn't the same thing as doing setInterval(doScrollCheck, 1).
The latter do not wait for doScrollCheck to actually finish, it would just fire it doScrollCheck function as fast as it can - THAT could be performance issue since there would be potentially dozens of overlapping calls to the same function.

I'm not sure if I've seen any other way of detecting that DOM is ready that by checking for *something* (is property available on documentElement in this case) in longer/shorter intervals.

Comment: Browsers don't multi-thread the Javascript environment by default. The setTimeout function won't be called until the active javascript thread has yielded execution (finished processing), at minimum.

Comment: While talking about dozens of overlapping calls I was refering to possible (while not recommended in terms of performance) executing something like `setInterval(doScrollCheck, 1)`.
In that case, browser would at least queue calls to doScrollCheck while (as you mentioned) **executing** one at a time.

Comment: I think what you're referring to, but is unclear from what you've said, is if multiple calls to doScrollCheck() are made from outside of the function then what you've described happens. If doScrollCheck() is only called once then the issue you describe does not happen. I suspect they've programmed the caller of this function to prevent it from doing that.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why it has been programmed the way as can be seen in jQuery source. It's a lot smarter (also in terms of performance) to check if something has happend and then act on the result and than maybe repeat the checking process.
For anyone that could read this discussion and be interested in learning more about jQuery source I highly recommend following screencast by Paul Irish http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/

Answer (score 0):

The minimum timeout interval is considerably greater than 1 millisecond.  If your code were doing a lot of DOM manipulation in there, then even with the pause being forced to a longer period you'd start to heat up the CPU.

Some new browsers (Firefox and Chrome, maybe Safari) raise that minimum timeout by a whole lot more for unfocused tabs and windows.

Even a millisecond is kind-of a long time for a modern CPU.